# Why does this constructor overload resolve incorrectly?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, overload-resolution

This is my (stripped) class and instantiation of one object:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
class Carray {
    typedef typename Allocator::size_type size_type;

    // ...

    explicit Carray(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()) {
        // ...
    }

    template<typename InputIterator>
    Carray(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

Carray<int> array(5, 10);
```

I would expect this to call the `Carray(size_type, const T&, const Allocator&)` constructor, but it doesn't. Apparantly this resolutes to `template<typename InputIterator> Carray(InputIterator, InputIterator, const Allocator&)`.

What should I change to make this work as intended? I find it weird also, because a call to `std::vector<int> v(5, 10)` works perfectly fine. And if I look at the definition of the constructors in my GCC's implementation I find this (I renamed some compiler-implementation names, like  `__n`):

```
template<typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >
class vector {
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef A allocator_type;

    // ...

    explicit vector(size_type n, const value_type& value = value_type(), const allocator_type& a = allocator_type());

    template<typename InputIterator>
    vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& a = allocator_type());

    // ...
};
```

which seems to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work with all iterator types (including pointers) and the current standard.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

// uses sfinae to determine if the passed in type is indeed an iterator
template <typename T>
struct is_iterator_impl
{
  typedef char yes[1];
  typedef char no[2];

  template <typename C>
  static yes& _test(typename C::iterator_category*);

  template <typename>
  static no& _test(...);

  static const bool value = sizeof(_test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
};

template <typename T, bool check = is_iterator_impl<T>::value>
struct is_iterator
{
  typedef void type;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_iterator<T, false>
{
};

template <typename T>
struct is_iterator<T*, false>
{
  typedef void type;
};

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  explicit foo(std::size_t n, const T& value) 
  {
    std::cout << "foo:size_t" << std::endl;
  }

  template<typename InputIterator>
  foo(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, typename is_iterator<InputIterator>::type* dummy = 0) 
  {
    std::cout << "foo::iterator" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  // should not cause a problem
  foo<int> f(1, 2);

  // using iterators is okay
  typedef std::vector<int> vec;
  vec v;
  foo<int> b(v.begin(), v.end());

  // using raw pointers - is okay
  char bar[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
  foo<char> c(bar, bar + sizeof(bar));
}
```

Explanation, an iterator must normally define several types such as `iterator_category`, and you can take advantage of this and sfinae to detect real iterators. Complication is that pointers are also iterators, but don't have these types defined (something `std::iterator_traits` provides a specialization for), so the above takes a similar approach, if the passed in type is a pointer, then it is by default treated as an iterator. This approach saves you having to test for integral types.

See demo: http://www.ideone.com/E9l1T

Comment: Thank you, this allows me to fully define my header without relying on either boost or non-C++03. I won't use this in production code of course (where boost::enable_if is much easier to use and appropriate).

Answer (score 7):

The explicit constructor expects a size_t and an int. You have provided two ints.

Substituting `int` for `InputIterator` makes the template a better match.

If you look closer at the standard containers, you will see that they use some template meta-programming to determine if the `InputIterator` could be a real iterator or if it is an integer type. This then redirects to a different construction.

**Edit**
Here is one way of doing it:

```
  template<class _InputIterator>
  vector(_InputIterator _First, _InputIterator _Last,
         const allocator_type& _Allocator = allocator_type() )
     : _MyAllocator(_Allocator), _MyBuffer(nullptr), _MySize(0), _MyCapacity(0)
  { _Construct(_First, _Last, typename std::is_integral<_InputIterator>::type()); }

private:
  template<class _IntegralT>
  void _Construct(_IntegralT _Count, _IntegralT _Value, std::true_type /* is_integral */)
  { _ConstructByCount(static_cast<size_type>(_Count), _Value); }

  template<class _IteratorT>
  void _Construct(_IteratorT _First, _IteratorT _Last, std::false_type /* !is_integral */)
  { _Construct(_First, _Last, typename std::iterator_traits<_IteratorT>::iterator_category()); }
```

You could also use boost::type_traits if the compiler doesn't have std::type_traits.

Comment: And how would I solve that? And the `vector` constructor expects a `size_t` and an `int` too, yet while passed `int, int` it will still resolve to the "correct one".

Comment: @nightcracker: `std::vector` behaves that way because the standard requires it to behave that way. It is an additional requirement imposed by the standard on top of the basic core language behavior. If you want your class to behave the same way too, you'll have to take extra steps (just like `std::vector` does). You can take a look at a specific implementation of `std::vector` to see how it is done there.

Comment: @AndreyT: OM-fin-G. I am blind. It's one line of code below the declaration and I managed to ignore it. IT EVEN HAD A COMMENT EXPLAINING IT. Is there any standard way of doing this without resolving to compiler intrinsics?

Comment: Is there any way with just the C++03 STL and without boost? It's not that I don't want to use boost, but I want this header file to be portable and avoid boost if possible.

Comment: @nightcracker - You would then have to do the is_integral yourself. The std one is just a base template defaulting to false and a bunch of specializations having a true value. Or tr1::type_traits for many compilers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It will eliminate the iterator constructor from consideration if two ints are passed:

```
template<typename InputIterator>
Carray(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
    const Allocator& alloc = Allocator(),
    typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_integral<InputIterator> >::type* dummy = 0) {
}
```

Reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/utility/enable_if.html

---

**EDIT**: responding to "Is there any way with just the C++03 STL and without boost?"

I don't know if std::type_traits is in C++03 or not -- I always have boost available, so I just use it. But you can try this. It will work in this specific case, but may not have the generality you require:

```
template <class T> class NotInt { typedef void* type; };
template <> class NotInt<int> { };

template <typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
class Carray {
  ...
  template<typename InputIterator>
  Carray(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
      const Allocator& alloc = Allocator(),
      typename NotInt<InputIterator>::type t = 0) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
  }
};
```

Comment: Is there any way with just the C++03 STL and without boost? It's not that I don't want to use boost, but I want this header file to be portable and avoid boost if possible.

Comment: @nightcracker: You can just write your own. Type traits like `is_integral` are relatively trivial to specify.

Answer (score 0):

The first constructor expects the 'value' argument to be passed by reference, while the second constructor expects the first 2 values to be passed by value. In my experience, C++ is quite strict about this distinction, try passing an integer variable instead of an integer value as the 2nd argument to your object constructor.